# Is it ok to override CSS property of class in the same stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, standards

Just a simple question: Is something like this ok ?

for example:

```
#formbox textarea,
#formbox input,
#formbox select {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 220px;
}

#formbox select {
    width: 232px;
}

#formbox textarea {
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I assigned width and margin-bottom property for select and textarea twice, is it ok, or should i just separate #formbox textarea, #formbox input, #formbox select and copy&paste properties that are the same for them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS declaration blocks *with the same selector* the last definition of a property is the only one applied.

The first `width: 220px` is 'useless' for a `select`/`textarea` (as it is overwritten by the same selectors below) - *but* it applies to `input`.

Choosing the approach shown, instead of a separate `input { width: .. }` is *perfectly OK*, coming down to preference.

(In the rules engine itself, it *doesn't matter* after the CSS is loaded.)